# Linux shell change directory,file not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have written my convert.sh shell

```
#!/bin/bash

alias proj="cd /home/milenko/MT8/meas_2015-06-29_19-18-28"

tsmp -nspw -wl 512 -rect -back -trf theo -run 99  263_V01_C05_R000_TEx_BH_131072H.ats 
tsmp -nspw -wl 512 -rect -back -trf theo -run 99  263_V01_C06_R000_TEy_BH_131072H.ats
```

This is my working directory

```
milenko@host:~/ProcMT64/old/version_september_2015/bin$ pwd
/home/milenko/ProcMT64/old/version_september_2015/bin
```

All executables and libraries are here, including tsmp.

```
ls -l tsmp
-rwxrwxr-x 1 milenko milenko 835143 Set 11 13:48 tsmp
```

But when I run my script

```
milenko@host:~/ProcMT64/old/version_september_2015/bin$ sh convert.sh
convert.sh: 5: convert.sh: tsmp: not found
convert.sh: 6: convert.sh: tsmp: not found
```

It seems that I do not understand alias.
Following chepner's comments,I have tried this

```
(cd /home/milenko/MT8/meas_2015-06-29_19-18-28 &&  ./tsmp -nspw -wl 512 -rect -back -trf theo -run 98)
```

But

```
c1.sh: line 3: ./tsmp: No such file or directory
```

Why?

Comment: Have you tried this? `chmod +x convert.sh` and then `./convert.sh`

Comment: @BogdanKobylinsky Yes.

Comment: Why is the alias there? You don't use it, aliases aren't expanded by default in shell scripts, and it won't be defined in the current shell after the script exits. Also, if you are using a `bash` shebang, you should either take Bogdan's suggestion, or run the script using `bash convert.sh`; `sh` != `bash`.

Comment: @chepner
Well, time series binaries are located in MT8,exe tsmp is located in another directory.Do you have any other ideas how to copy ats before execution?

Comment: You aren't copying anything now. You're simply defining an alias that is never used. Your script never changes the working directory.

Comment: @chepner See edit please!

Comment: Like I said, the alias is useless; you just want to run the `cd` command.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94753/discussion-between-richard-rublev-and-chepner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tsmp` is not in your `PATH` environment variable, so you have to be explicit about where it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

alias proj="cd /home/milenko/MT8/meas_2015-06-29_19-18-28"

./tsmp -nspw -wl 512 -rect -back -trf theo -run 99  263_V01_C05_R000_TEx_BH_131072H.ats 
./tsmp -nspw -wl 512 -rect -back -trf theo -run 99  263_V01_C06_R000_TEy_BH_131072H.ats
```

Comment: Works now,I just forgot about PATH!

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your current working directory is not in your `PATH` environment variable.

You could add it in your script via:

```
export PATH=.:$PATH
```

However, a better approach would be to explicitly list the location with just

```
./tsmp -nspw -wl 512 -rect -back -trf theo -run 99  263_V01_C05_R000_TEx_BH_131072H.ats 
./tsmp -nspw -wl 512 -rect -back -trf theo -run 99  263_V01_C06_R000_TEy_BH_131072H.ats
^^ pre-fix with current directory
```